# Managing Cache that goes into user-data of Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, cache

In Chrome browser, we have GPUCache, ShaderCache, CacheStorage, ScriptCache,
now we have DawnCache, GrShaderCache.

They just keep making new folder for temp files and even mixing it into the user-data.

I'm already using
`--disk-cache-dir="FOLDER" --user-data-dir="FOLDER2"`

The problem is that lots of cache folders are getting saved into userdata,
is the "disk cache dir" now being ignored or is there a different commandline for this.

Does anyone know of script/repo that safely cleans these temp files already?

Comment: Which folders in user-data do you back up? I'm managing over 300+ profiles so disk usages is quite large. at the moment I'm doing excluding copies in my batch script, but new versions introduces new temp folders. its hard to keep up now.